# npm warnings about package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to follow socket.io simple chat tutorial using nodeJS:
[socket.io chat with nodeJS](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

I only got to the place where you need to install express:

```
npm install --save express@4.15.2
```

and got these warnings:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\James\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\James\package.json'
```

I did create the folder `chat-example` with `package.json` in it, as told in the tutorial.
Are these warnings due to the fact that nodeJS installs the 'express' package in a different location than my newly created `chat-example` folder with the `package.json` file so it doesn't find it?
I did install nodeJS a long time ago, and probably it now installs pacakges into a different location.

How can I delete the express I installed, and re-install it in the correct folder?

How do I see where nodeJS is currently installing packages and how can I change that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every project based on Node and npm needs a package.json file in its root directory. You can create one with this command:

```
npm init
```

You can just hit enter for every question in the dialog that follows, don't worry, you can edit everything later.

After that, you can execute the install command to add express or any other package.

Comment: But using npm init, it creates the json for you, but on the tutorial above, it suggest you create the package.json to a predefined location, and then install the package 'express', or am I missing something?

Comment: You can use npm init or create the package.json file yourself, the result is the same

Comment: Ok I got it, and now the warnings are gone, but in the tutorial it wants you to save the package.json in a folder called "example-chat".. but after using npm init, I don't even know where this project was created

Comment: The package.json is located in the directory where you were when you executed the nomination init command. If you want to stick to the tutorial 100% you can rename the directory you are in and edit the project name in package.json, or create a dir with mkdir example-chat && cd example chat - then execute npm init again

Comment: Reading your question again, I think the only mistake you made initially was that you didn't change to the example-chat directory before you tried installing express

Comment: Ok I undersatnd it now. so I should go to the folder chat-example and run the cmd from there. 1 more thing: If I want to create the chat-system for a website I already have, what would be the best location to place the nodeJS project? is it inside the website folder (htdocs, if using XAMPP) or somewhere else?